# I am trying to find a word that describes a person who is contrary, but not insubordinate, argumentative, but not froward

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I am trying to find a word that describes a person who is contrary, but not insubordinate, argumentative, but not froward. This person frequently falls back to, "we've never done it that way." when told to do something different.  And, has a tone in that statement that is meant to undermine only the directive, but not authority of the manager issuing the directive.  This person is very careful to NOT be explicitly insubordinate.

Comment: By definition, "a tone meant to undermine the authority of the manager" is insubordinate?

Comment: Yes, but she is careful to not be insubordinate.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the word or term used to describe a person who intentionally ignores a rule/regulation/order](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/200825/what-is-the-word-or-term-used-to-describe-a-person-who-intentionally-ignores-a-r)

Comment: Perhaps some combination of [*assertive*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assertiveness) and [*conservative*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conservatism), using the flavour of the linked articles but not necessarily fully in the senses they indicate.

Comment: No, I don't, that's why I said, "is very careful to NOT be ...."

Answer (score 1):

**Rule-bound** or **process-bound,** possibly to the point of **passive aggression.**

There is some advantage in having people on your team that resist arbitrary orders, since they can help you avoid mistakes when your orders are given in greater haste than you might like.  The key is to understand what *justifies* the opposition in the other's mind. Figure that out, and you'll have the term to describe it right at hand.

In my experience, people working at a clerical or minor technical level are often like this.  They lack the knowledge or the authority to handle a broader scope of action, but their knowledge of the existing rules or processes makes it possible for them to *temporarily* oppose those who do. It's a *status* thing, mediated by words, but also by the tone and body language you describe.

It's hard to find an English word that covers all of this from the standpoint of the *behavior*, since **insolent** sounds too strong for what you describe, as does **mulish**.  This is why a term related to the person's *motivation* may be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

***recalcitrant***   [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/recalcitrant) says:

> If you describe someone or something as recalcitrant, you mean that
>   they are unwilling to obey orders or are difficult to deal with.
>
> [Example]: The danger is that recalcitrant local authorities will
>   reject their responsibilities.

[Oxford English Dictionaries](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/recalcitrant) says:

> Having an obstinately uncooperative attitude towards authority or
>   discipline

*From personal experience:* A recalcitrant person falls short of being insubordinate.  He will progress towards a goal, but at an agonizing slow pace.  His forte is in creating problems where none exist.  One such person was described to me as:

> Getting him to do anything is like pushing on a string.

Answer (score 0):

This person sounds 'stubborn', perhaps 'stuck in their ways' and 'unwilling/resistant to change'. Or perhaps they are 'critical'?

It sounds as though you are looking for a word that doesn't carry negative overtones - perhaps for an appraisal report? If so, I understand why you don't want to use terms like 'insubordinate'. Of my four suggestions, the first two do have negative connotations and the last two don't, necessarily.

When I type 'contrary' into Thesaurus.com I get the following list:
adverse
antithetical
conflicting
contradictory
discordant
hostile
inconsistent
inimical
negative
opposed
paradoxical
wrongheaded
anti
antipodal
converse
counter
dissident
nonconformist
recusant
refractory
reverse
antipathetic
antipodean
balky
clashing
contrariant
contumacious
diametric
dissentient
froward
headstrong
insubordinate
intractable
nonconforming
obstinate
ornery
perverse
rebellious
recalcitrant
restive
stubborn
unruly
wayward

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you Beth, but i'm looking for something a bit more nuanced, yet comprehensive.  This isn't for any evaluation of her, so I'm not shying away from negative overtones.  What is difficult here is that much of the nuance I'm attempting to capture in the adjective is only conveyed in her tone and body language, which naturally don't translate to internet text :).

Answer (score 0):

An adjective is difficult, but perhaps *silently insubordinate* will do, especially if body language is involved.

> #### Examples of an employee resisting authority
>
> **'Silent' Insubordination**
>
> An employee can convey his resistance to authority without saying a word. Eye rolling, sighs, gestures and other outward displays of "attitude" signal disrespect towards the manager and clearly demonstrate the employee's dissatisfaction with directives. Although the employee may actually perform the tasks requested of him -- albeit reluctantly -- the passive-aggressive behavior is an outward example of his resistance to authority.
>
> [smallbusiness.chron.com](http://smallbusiness.chron.com/examples-employee-resisting-authority-14523.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to thank everyone who offered an solution to my word-sleuthing.  Two of you had very helpful responses.   I probably did not fully articulate this person's behavior; if added 'furtive' and 'manipulative', that may...MAY have helped.
So I will go with FURTIVE.  Again, thanks to all of you.

Stacy